# Send org-mode subtree to certain file, and headline

Tags: org-mode

In many case, I often wants to send a org-mode subtree to certain file, at certain headline.  Here is an example workflow of such todo:

Let's say I capture any todos to `inbox.org` first, as many todos occur asynchrounously, those pops into my mind.  Later, I view them in the agenda file, and start dispatching them into more adequate org file, at adequate headline (e.g. `projecta.org`, `* todo` heading)

I wondered if I can achieve this in a existing elisp.  In more systematical description, I imagine it to be like an `org-capture`, but it does not create a new entry; it sends current subtree to the whatever defined destination.

Is there any such feature?

Comment: Have you already looked at `org-refile` and customizing `org-refile-targets` and/or `org-refile-use-outline-path`?  If so, please distinguish how what you seek is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that, `org-refile` <kbd>C-c C-w</kbd> is what I wanted.